# sql query for by periods

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I will have 2 fields in my table, NEXTTIME and ENDTIME, the table name is VISIT.

I will get a value from my page which is 00:05:00 or sth like that. the minimum is 5 minute.

I will have to query from the database based on that value.

I will get the earliest NEXTTIME and that time + 00:05:00.

Let's say the earlist NEXTTIME is 06:44.

My query will be like 06:45, 06:50, and so on..

I will also have another input value which is interval time.

Nvm that.

I just wanna know how to get the query by interval.

The result would be looked like this.
[image]

NEXTTIME : ENDTIME

06:55:00 ~ 06:58:00

07:25:00 ~ 07:28:00

07:35:00 ~ 08:52:00

08:38:00 ~ 08:48:00

08:40:00 ~ 08:54:00

08:43:00 ~ 09:36:00

09:12:00 ~ 09:30:00

Comment: So, you want half hours to be rows, and five minutes intervals to be columns? And for each columns, you want the number of visits for this period of 5 minutes, is that correct?

Comment: Can you provide sample data so that we us all may test some queries against our local tests database?

Comment: I already edited the question with sample data.

Comment: Dont you have any Id in your table?

Comment: Do you mean unique ID? No, I don't have that in my table.

Comment: And what is the result expected from these sample rows for what you want to achieve?

Comment: Same as the picture. If u minus ENDTIME-NEXTTIME, you will have the transaction time. How many customers' transaction time is less than 5 minute or 10 minute or .. more than 50 minutes for each period.

Comment: I havent got time to work this through at the moment. if you build a table of periods and intervals as a couple of working tables you can do this with a pivot.] http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx should hopefully get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's based on the information provided and my understanding of your question the solution I'm proposing. In order to meet the chart periods, only change the periods within both the select statements and the where clauses for each unioned query.

```
USE master
GO

create database Tests
GO

USE Tests
GO

create table Visits (
    nexttime    datetime    not null
    , endtime   datetime    not null
)
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'06:55:00', N'06:58:00'
insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'07:25:00', N'07:28:00'
insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'07:35:00', N'08:52:00'
insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'08:38:00', N'08:48:00'
insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'08:40:00', N'08:54:00'
insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'08:43:00', N'09:36:00'
insert into Visits (nexttime, endtime) select N'09:12:00', N'09:30:00'

COMMIT

select N'06:30 - 07:00' as period
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 5 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [5:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 10 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) as [10:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 15 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [15:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 20 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as [20:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 25 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [25:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 30 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [30:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 35 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [35:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 40 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as [40:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 45 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [45:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [50:00] 
from Visits
where nexttime between CONVERT(datetime, N'06:30:00', 108) and CONVERT(datetime, N'07:00:00', 108)
union
select N'07:00 - 07:30' as period
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 5 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [5:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 10 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) as [10:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 15 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [15:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 20 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as [20:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 25 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [25:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 30 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [30:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 35 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [35:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 40 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as [40:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 45 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [45:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [50:00] 
from Visits
where nexttime between CONVERT(datetime, N'07:00:00', 108) and CONVERT(datetime, N'07:30:00', 108)
union
select N'07:30 - 08:00' as period
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 5 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [5:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 10 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) as [10:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 15 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [15:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 20 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as [20:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 25 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [25:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 30 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [30:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 35 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [35:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 40 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as [40:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 45 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [45:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [50:00] 
from Visits
where nexttime between CONVERT(datetime, N'07:30:00', 108) and CONVERT(datetime, N'08:00:00', 108)
union
select N'08:00 - 08:30' as period
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 5 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [5:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 10 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) as [10:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 15 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [15:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 20 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as [20:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 25 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [25:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 30 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [30:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 35 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [35:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 40 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as [40:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 45 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [45:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [50:00] 
from Visits
where nexttime between CONVERT(datetime, N'08:00:00', 108) and CONVERT(datetime, N'08:30:00', 108)
union
select N'08:30 - 09:00' as period
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 5 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [5:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 10 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) as [10:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 15 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [15:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 20 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as [20:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 25 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [25:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 30 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [30:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 35 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [35:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 40 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as [40:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 45 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [45:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [50:00] 
from Visits
where nexttime between CONVERT(datetime, N'08:30:00', 108) and CONVERT(datetime, N'09:00:00', 108)
union
select N'09:00 - 09:30' as period
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 5 and 10 then 1 else 0 end) as [5:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 10 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) as [10:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 15 and 20 then 1 else 0 end) as [15:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 20 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as [20:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 25 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as [25:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 30 and 35 then 1 else 0 end) as [30:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 35 and 40 then 1 else 0 end) as [35:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 40 and 45 then 1 else 0 end) as [40:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) between 45 and 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [45:00]
    , SUM(case when DATEDIFF(MI, nexttime, endtime) >= 50 then 1 else 0 end) as [50:00] 
from Visits
where nexttime between CONVERT(datetime, N'09:00:00', 108) and CONVERT(datetime, N'09:30:00', 108)
```

**Output**

```
╔══════════════╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║06:30 - 07:00 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
╠══════════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║07:00 - 07:30 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
╠══════════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║07:30 - 08:00 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║
╠══════════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║08:00 - 08:30 ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║
╠══════════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║08:30 - 09:00 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║
╠══════════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║09:00 - 09:30 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
╚══════════════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Feel free to say whether I have correctly understood your question or not.

Comment: that's great.. But, as I said.. Period and Interval Time is changeable. Like the user will key in 5 minutes or 15 minutes for both.

Comment: we have to calculate accordingly.

Comment: the values in the `between` clauses are changeable. Just set in parameters and you're through. Would this meet the requirements?

Comment: kind of.. but.. what i really need is.. let's say 8:00 to 10:00. if the period time is 0:30, there will b 4 rows, if it is 0:15, there will b 8 rows and so on..

Comment: You will then need to create a stored procedure that takes the required interval as input parameter, then use a working table to insert rows according to what is the input parameter value so your period of time is represented, then update this table according to the intervals.